# Ansbile issue replacing variables

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible and I am using variables to use awx polls, the case is that when I want to use these variables in the get_url task

```
- name: Download Artifact
  get_url: "{{ url_artifact }}"
    dest: "/tmp/artifacts/{{ app_name }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
```

When I launch an ansible-playbook from my local I get this error

```
The offending line appears to be:

      get_url: "{{ url_artifact }}"
        dest: "/tmp/artifacts/{{ app_name }}"
        ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with 
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

with_items:
  - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

Does anyone know what can be due?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the missing url key ([docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html))
Try the following

```
    - name: Download Artifact
      get_url:
        url: "{{ url_artifact }}"
        dest: "/tmp/artifacts/{{ app_name }}"
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
```

Comment: yes! I forgot the url parameter! thank you!